# PHP PDO SQL - update inner join query freezes during execution

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I need to run a daily PHP script that downloads a data file and executes a bunch of SQL Queries in sequence to import and optimize the data.

I'm having a problem executing one of my queries within PHP which appears to freeze the mysqld process on my server. Oddly, running the same query does not case a similar problem when run from the Sequel Pro Database client program (Mac).

The query is running an update on a large table with over a million rows. Here is the stored procedure I'm using:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE spSetTripIdInStopTimes()
BEGIN 

-- SET META_TRIP_ID IN IMPORT_STOP_TIMES    
UPDATE import_stop_times 
INNER JOIN ref_trips ON 
(
    import_stop_times.trip_id = ref_trips.trip_id 
    AND import_stop_times.meta_agency_id =ref_trips.meta_agency_id
) 
 SET import_stop_times.meta_trip_id = ref_trips.meta_trip_id;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

When the procedure is called with

```
CALL spSetTripIdInStopTimes;
```

inside Sequel Pro, the result is 1241483 rows affected and the time taken is around 90 seconds.

With PHP PDO I run the same command with

```
$result = $database->runExecQuery("CALL spSetTripIdInStopTimes");
```

However, it gets stuck on this query for over 24 hrs and still has not completed. When I cancel the PHP script I can see that the mysqld process is still taking %99.5 CPU. At this point I restart SQL with 'sudo service mysql restart'.

I also tried using PHP's mysqli, but the freezing also occurs with this method.

```
$mysqli->query("CALL spSetTripIdInStopTimes")
```

Would anyone be able to reason why this is happening or suggest another method?

Thank you in advance.

Note: I also tried using the older mysql on PHP, but the version I'm using (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14) tells me the command is deprecated and stops the script.

[UPDATE]

I've also tried running the stored procedure directly on the command line:

```
mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --execute="call spSetTripIdInStopTimes()" [tablename]
```

which worked.

So I tried running the same command with PHP's [exec() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
exec("mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --execute=\"call spSetTripIdInStopTimes()\" [table name]");
```

Unfortunately, it stills hangs. I'm starting to wonder if this is due to the limitation or overhead of PHP.

[UPDATE 2]
Here is the array of PHP PDO connection options I use:

```
array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
// Allow file reading, need following settings to import data from txt files
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true)
```

[UPDATE 3]

I'm using a custom database object, so I'll show the function for $database->runExecQuery() for clarification:

```
  function runExecQuery($queryString)
    {
        $db = $this-> getConnection(); // Connect to database

        try{
            return array(
                "success"=> true,
                "data"=>$db->exec($queryString)
            );
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex)
        {
            return array(
                "success"=> false,
                "errMessage"=> "ERROR[{$ex->getCode()}]".($this-> Debug ? "{$ex}" : "")
            );
        }
    }
```

The variable $db is the connection variable that is initialized as follows:

```
// Create address string
$db_address = 
            "mysql:host={$settings['db_hostname']};".
            "dbname={$settings['db_name']};".
            "charset={$settings['db_charset']}";    
// Create connection to database
$db = new PDO($db_address, $settings['db_user'], $settings['db_pw'], $options);
```

where $options is the array from [Update 2].

[Update 4]

Mihai's suggestion of changing `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false` had some promising results as query appeared to finish. However, after more testing I found that the PHP script will sometimes still hang on the Query about 50% of the time it is run.  This is true even with the same set of data in the SQL tables.

Comment: Nothing in error logs?

Comment: There's no errors in the log file, though there is a warning: 
[Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: (Response to removed comment) I don't believe the delimiter would cause the problem because the stored procedure is working in Sequel Pro with no errors. Also, on my server the semi colon appears to be the default delimiter which is why I had to temporary change it with DELIMITER ;; in order to create the procedure.

Comment: Its more like sidestepping the issue but why not run the UPDATE directly?

Comment: I need to run the update after importing a bunch of data on a daily basis at 1:00 am in the morning. This is why I'm using a cron job to run the queries in PHP.

Comment: If you run the UPDATE with PDO does it  still hang?

Comment: I tried running a different UPDATE with PDO for testing on the same table and it works fine, but the stored procedure (spSetTripIdInStopTimes) still hangs with PDO. I'm wondering if there is a problem with PHP overhead.

Comment: `$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` add this line in your connection and put your statement in a try catch block.Edit your question with the exception message,if any

Comment: What hppens if you set MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY to false

Comment: Great news, your suggestion of MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY set to false worked!